# Out of Memory exception in ASP.NET web forms

Tags: .net, iis, iis-8, application-pool, worker-process

We have a legacy web application built in ASP.NET web forms targeting CLR 2.0 and .NET framework 3.5 in a web farm environment . In the recent days, we have noticed some OOM exceptions. We know the memory limitation of w3wp for 32 bit apps is 3GB as we have enabled the 3GB switch.

We would like to make the below changes to app pool settings for the app pool that is causing the OOM issue.

1. If the Virtual memory of 2.5 GB is reached, recycle the application pool using the Disable overlapped recycle to true.
2. As we are in a web farm environment, can we make use of web garden scenario using more than one w3WP ( with in the web servers). Reasoning behind this is each w3wp will have its own memory limitation of 3 GB.

Question:

1. Is it recommended to use virtual memory limit or private memory limit.? if not a combination of both.
2. Is it recommended to have Disable overlapped recycle to true / false. should we change the shutdown time limit from 90 sec to 180 sec giving the app pool enough time to finish the processing of existing requesting as a new app pool is the process of serving the requests.
3. Are their any drawback in using web garden in with a web farm scenario like above.

We need some breathing room to work on the 64 bit migration and these are only temporary fixes.

Comment: I don't think either #1 or #2 will help. For ASP.Net, web gardens have generally caused more problems than they've solved. And for the actual out of memory exception, this exception is more often thrown due to address space use for the memory than for memory use itself.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn we know where is the bottleneck and are working on the permanent fix. so wanted to go with  config change of adding more (like 2) worker process per app pool ( 2 X 4 = 8GB ) . what are the problem do you see in this ?